# How do I use get_mcf and get_ga together in Package "RGA"?

Tags: r, google-api, google-analytics-api, r-package

I need to have data from both Google Analytics API  and Analytics Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API togrther.  I employed get_mcf option in RGA package in R but it deos not allow me to query dimensions and metrics of Google Analytics API. For instance ga:data in the following code. Is there any way?

```
 ga_data <- get_mcf(XXXXXXX, start.date = "30daysAgo", end.date = "today",
                   metrics = "mcf:totalConversions",
                   dimensions = "mcf:source,ga:date")
```